# Disconnect chrome sender from the receiver

Tags: chromecast

Is there an equivalent of http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#leaveApplication(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient) for Chrome?
I do not want to call Session.stop(), I want to disconnect from the sender. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that API is missing from Chrome SDK. The closest equivalent is closing the tab.

Comment: is there a plan to add it in the future?

Comment: So If someone is having issue disconnecting cast sender from the receiver, what he can do? - @Ali Naddaf